# Vertical spacing with beamer and pstricks using Miktex

Tags: beamer, miktex, pstricks

I have some old files which I haven't used for a long time. They now produce different vertical layouts in beamer.

MWE (test.tex):

```
\documentclass[dvips]{beamer}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{unit=1mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test}
line 1

line 2

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\pspicture(0,0)(60,60)
\psframe(0,0)(60,60)
\endpspicture
\end{center}
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}

line 3

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Workflow:

```
latex test
dvips -P pdf test
ps2pdf test.ps
```

Running this using an old Miktex from late 2014 gives the following.

[image: Result from old Miktex]

Running this using the current Miktex gives the following.

[image: Current Miktex]

The vertical spacing is different for the two runs. Does anyone know what's changed to cause this? Thanks.

Update

Links to log files:

Miktex 2014 - https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuihY7Zd3CrNee0RytQa2zBX5qw

Miktex 2019 - https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuihY7Zd3CrNeh9xWI_j5BVIHgg

Comment: Can you put `\listfiles` into your document and then show us the list of packages from the .log file for both installations?

Comment: @samcarter I have provided links to the log files thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity : have you tried using `\begin{pspicture} ... \end{pspicture}` instead of `\pspicture ... \endpspicture`?

Comment: Instead of the environment `center` use a single `\centering`. Does it help?

Comment: ok, what happens if you run the document with `xelatex` and _without_ the optional argument `[dvips]`??

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: you don't need `[H]` in beamer, as beamer does not have a foating mechanism

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with pstricks. You see it also with pdflatex and a simple rule.

Between 2017 and 2018 beamer added in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty` the command

```
\setlength\partopsep{\z@skip}
```

And this means that lists now have around 3pt less spacing before and after them. The figure environment is defined internally to use `center` which is a list. Side remark: that means that there is no need to add the center environment manually.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test}
line 1

line 2

\begin{center}
\the\partopsep %0pt in 2018, 3.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt in 2017
\rule{60mm}{60mm}
\end{center}

line 3

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The commit to change this was https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/8b1991979b697124cc002a52aa129c57d508eacf (to fix the alignment for lists with allowframebreak, https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/506)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Ulrike. It’s a pity this change makes old slides behave differently now although it’s easy to force the old separation.