# Wrong slide size with beamer, pstricks and Texlive

Tags: beamer, pstricks, dvips, miktex2.9, texlive-2018

This is a followup of my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472817/vertical-spacing-with-beamer-and-pstricks-using-miktex) and uses the same setup.

MWE (`test.tex`):

```
\documentclass[dvips]{beamer}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{unit=1mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test}
line 1

line 2

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\pspicture(0,0)(60,60)
\psframe(0,0)(60,60)
\endpspicture
\end{center}
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}

line 3

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Workflow:

```
latex test
dvips -P pdf test
ps2pdf test.ps
```

Running this with Tex Live 2018 gives a wrong slide size. The problem seems to be in running dvips. Under Tex Live, the header in the postscript file is

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0
%%Creator: dvips(k) 5.998 Copyright 2018 Radical Eye Software
%%Title: test.dvi
%%CreationDate: Wed Mar 13 00:35:25 2019
%%Pages: 1
%%PageOrder: Ascend
%%Orientation: Landscape
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 273 363
%%DocumentFonts: CMSS12 CMSS10
%%EndComments
%DVIPSWebPage: (www.radicaleye.com)
%DVIPSCommandLine: dvips -P pdf test
```

Running dvips under MiKTeX gives the correct slide size:

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0
%%Creator: dvips(k) 5.998 Copyright 2018 Radical Eye Software
%%Title: test.dvi
%%CreationDate: Wed Mar 13 00:34:23 2019
%%Pages: 1
%%PageOrder: Ascend
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 363 273
%%DocumentFonts: CMSS12 CMSS10
%%EndComments
%DVIPSWebPage: (www.radicaleye.com)
%DVIPSCommandLine: dvips -P pdf test
```

Has anyone else noticed this problem and is there a fix?

Thanks.

Comment: With texlive2019 I get `%%BoundingBox: 0 0 363 273`

Comment: try `divps -t unknown ...`

Comment: @samcarter Good to know it's fixed. BTW I thought texlive2019 wasn't available yet.

Comment: @Herbert Your suggestion doesn't work either. It's strange that both versions of dvips have the same version number and yet produce different results.

Comment: that is not strange. It is a problem with the divps-config file from beamer/tikz or the `config.ps` file. It seems that they are different for TL and MikTeX

Comment: @user41974 TL2019 is available as pre-test

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as probably caused by old texlive version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we use a single frame to create the following effect?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64942/can-we-use-a-single-frame-to-create-the-following-effect)